# What is the probability that at least one card is in the right box

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> Four Christmas cards are randomly placed in their recipients' boxes
>   (one in every box). What is the probability that at least one card is
>   in the right box?

So, if we number the boxes with $1,2,3,4$ and let the first card should be placed in the box with number $1$, the second in the box with number $2$, etc. If only one card is in the right box, we have $4$ possibilities; if only two cards are in the right boxes, we have $6$ possibilities. I am having troubles with what happens when three cards are in the right boxes. Do we have only $1$ way or $4$ ways?

Comment: There are only $4!=24$ cases.  Just do it by hand if nothing else comes to mind.

Comment: You are talking about all possibilities. I can calculate this.

Comment: Right.  Write them all down.  Do it by hand. If you want to do it in general, read about [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) but that is pointless overkill for four elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the more fundamental approaches that students first being exposed to [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) (*but maybe even before being told the name of the objects they are counting*) will come up with will be to use [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ be the event that the first, second, third, and fourth boxes contain the correct letter respectively.

We are tasked with calculating $Pr(X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3\cup X_4)$, the probability that at least one of the boxes contains the correct letter.

We expand this via inclusion-exclusion as:

$$Pr(X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3\cup X_4) = Pr(X_1)+Pr(X_2)+Pr(X_3)+Pr(X_4)-Pr(X_1\cap X_2)-Pr(X_1\cap X_3)-\dots-Pr(X_3\cap X_4)+Pr(X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3)+\dots+Pr(X_2\cap X_3\cap X_4)-Pr(X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3\cap X_4)$$

We calculate each individual term in the above.  By symmetry, we need only calculate the four probabilities $Pr(X_1),Pr(X_1\cap X_2),Pr(X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3)$ and $Pr(X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3\cap X_4)$

We find that the probability that the first letter is in the correct box will be $\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3!}{4!}$ as given the first letter is in the correct box there are $3!$ ways to arrange the remaining letters without any consideration as to whether any are correct or not.

Similarly, we find $Pr(X_1\cap X_2)=\frac{2!}{4!}, Pr(X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3)=\frac{1!}{4!}$ and $Pr(X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3\cap X_4)=\frac{0!}{4!}$.  (*Remember: $0!$ is equal to $1$*)

Grouping the terms together, we have then

$$Pr(X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3\cup X_4) = \dfrac{\binom{4}{1}3!-\binom{4}{2}2!+\binom{4}{3}1!-\binom{4}{4}0!}{4!} = \dfrac{15}{24}$$

---

Indeed, what we just calculated is one of the ways to derive the value for $!n$, the number of derangements of an $n$ element set, i.e. the number of permutations in $S_n$ with no fixed points.  We have:

$$!n = n!-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(-1\right)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k}(n-k)!$$

Comment: Zubin's answer is also correct. $\frac{15}{24}=\frac{5}{8}$. And it's also the answer I obtained :)

Comment: @NikolDimitrova no, it is correct.  Notice that $\frac{15}{24} = \frac{3\cdot 5}{3\cdot 8}=\frac{5}{8}$.  Using the floor function and $\frac{n!}{e}$ and such is just another formula for the number of derangements which one can prove and verify using other techniques, though often not the first one that someone studies or is introduced to.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! I am gonna take a little time and try to understand all solutions!

Answer (score 3):

The probability that at least one card is in the right box is $1$ minus the probability that *no* cards are in the right boxes. The latter is a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

There are $n!$ total arrangements, and you are interested in the probability of *not* getting a derangement, which is $$1-\displaystyle\frac{\left\lfloor\displaystyle\frac{n!}{e}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor}{n!}$$
Your problem is the case $n=4$, for which we have

$$1-\displaystyle\frac{\left\lfloor\displaystyle\frac{4!}{e}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor}{4!} =1 -\frac{9}{24} = \boxed{\,\frac{5}{8}\,\,} $$

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations are off, because you only focus on the cards in the right box, and forget to take  into account the cards that have to end up in the wrong box.

Now, you seem to be trying to count the number of ways to get at least $1$ card in the right box by adding up the number of ways to get exactly $1$ in the right box, exactly $2$, exactly $3$, and exactly $4$. You don't use the word 'exactly' yourself, but this is certainly implied by your very method of breaking the problem down the way you do. Well, you can certainly do this as a strategy, so so far so good.

However, you then say:

> If only one card is in the right box, we have $4$ possibilities

No.  There are $4$ possibilities to pick a box with the right card, but for each of those, there are $2$ ways to distribute the $3$ remaining cards for the $3$ remaining boxes so that the other cards are all in the wrong box. For example, both distributions $1342$ and $1423$ have $1$ in the right place, but the other three in the wrong box. So, you get $4 \cdot 2 = 8$ ways to get exactly $1$ card in the right box.

> if only two cards are in the right boxes, we have $6$ possibilities.

This turns out to be correct, but I bet you were still just thinking about the number of ways to pick the two 'correct' boxes ... you still need to think about in how many ways the other two cards can end up in the wrong box .. but with 2 cards and 2 boxes left there is only one way to get them both wrong. So, it is $6 \cdot 1 = 6$ ways to get exactly 2 cards in the right box.

> I am having troubles with what happens when three cards are in the right boxes. Do we have only $1$ way or $4$ ways?

Neither. There are $0$ ways: if three cards are in the right box ... then the fourth is as well!  So, here is the perfect example of how not thinking about how the remaining cards have to be in the wrong box will get you the wrong answer.

Now, of course, there is exactly $1$ way to get all $4$ cards in the right box, and in that case there are no 'wrong' cards to worry about.

So, the number of ways to get at least $1$ card in the right box is $4 \cdot 2 + 6 \cdot 1 + 1 = 8+6+1=15$, meaning that the probability to get at least $1$ card in the right box is $\boxed{\frac{15}{24}}$

Comment: This is one way. So $4+6+1=11$.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova Oh really?  Describe it to us then.

Comment: Going by your Post, you are trying to count the number of ways to get at least $1$ card in the right box by adding up the number of ways to get *exactly* $1$ in the right box, exactly $2$, exactly $3$, and *exactly* $4$ .... but what I am telling you is that there is *no* way to get *exactly* $3$ cards in the right box.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to tell me. If at least three cards are in the right box, then the fourth is as well! So we have $1$ possibility.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova do not confuse the statement "*If* **exactly** *three cards are in the correct box*" with the statement "*If at least three cards are in the correct box*" or the statement "*If the first three cards are in the correct box.*"  It is impossible for exactly three but not four cards to be in the correct box.

Comment: Where did you see the word 'exactly' in my sentence?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova it is implied by the fact that you are breaking apart based on the number of cards in the correct boxes.  If you want to talk about "*at least*" instead, then you should have been doing that for all of your other cases as well, but then the resulting sum is meaningless.

Comment: If I continue my solution, we have $6 + 4 + 1 = 11$. The total possibilities are $4!=24$. So my answer is $P(A)=\dfrac{11}{24}$. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem?  You have several.  First, "The number of ways of having at least 1 card in the wrong spot" is not $4$.  Similarly for the other terms you calculated.  Next, "The number of ways of having at least 1 correct card in its box" + "The number of ways of having at least 2 correct cards in its box" + ... "The number of ways of having at least 4 correct cards in its box" overcounts badly as an arrangement with exactly three in the wrong spot was counted in each of the first three terms.  You could correct this by using *exactly* instead of *at least*, but this is tedious and not ideal.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova The problem is that you don't take into account the 'wrong' cards. For example, with 1 card in the right box, there are 2 ways to get the other three all in the wrong box.

Comment: @JMoravitz, do you think you could try not to be completely rude to me? I am trying to understand, you see?

Answer (score -2):

If 3 cards are in the correct box, then the fourth card must be in the remaining box. There is only 1 way to do this.

Comment: If exactly $3$ and not $4$ cards are in the correct box, then the fourth card must be in the remaining box... but then we have $4$ cards in the correct boxes, not $3$, a contradiction.  Do not confuse this with "If *at least 3* cards are in the correct box" or "If *the first three* cards are in the correct box"